# VBA: download the grouped images in each cell

Tags: excel, vba

How to quickly download the grouped images in each cell [column B] by image name in respective rows [column A].

I grouped the images in each cell with help from: [VBA: auto group multile pictures kept in each excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252927/vba-auto-group-multile-pictures-kept-in-each-excel-cell)

Comment: Download from where, to where?

Comment: From excel sheet to a desktop folder.

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?10902-Solved-Help-Need-to-export-image-from-Excel

Comment: The problem is there are multiple grouped images in each cells up to 200 rows in column B. And the VBA [I tried others as well] is not considering cells in images are grouped.